# Problemas con TOMCAT 7

Tags: tomcat

tengo una aplicacion web montada con Tomcat 7 en un servidor con SO Debian 7, y hace unos dias cuando enciendo el servidor la aplicacion levanta perfectamente pero en menos de 5 minutos deja de funcionar, me di cuenta de que tomcat esta consumiendo toda la memoria del server, pero en la configuracion tiene puesto que consuma 2 gb y me esta consumiendo los 4 que tiene el servidor. ¿Como puedo solucionar el problema?. Saludos

este es el error en los logs de catalina que veo java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que la aplicación necesite más espacio por su propia arquitectura.Actualmente las aplicaciones usan librerías muy grandes, que cargan muchas clases y además hacen uso de proxy y carga dinámica de clases que hacen uso del espacio PermGen. Este caso se da cuando la excepción con el error se produce nada mas arrancar el servidor web o de aplicaciones o al acceder a la aplicación como creo que es tu caso. Para resolver este problema basta con aumentar el tamaño máximo de la memoria de tipo PermGen.
En Java, hay varios parámetros para controlar el tamaño inicial y el tamaño máximo que puede tomar la máquina virtual.

- ***Xms128m***: Tamaño de inicio de la Máquina Virtual el valor por defecto son 64Mb. Si se aumenta este valor, se elimina el tiempo que se tardaría en aumentar el tamaño en memoria de la máquina virtual si se llegara el caso de que se necesitara más memoria, por lo que aumentaría el rendimiento en los casos que la aplicación haga uso intensivo de la memoria.
- ***Xmx128m***: Tamaño máximo de la máquina virtual de Java a 128Mb. Si la aplicación supera el tamaño máximo de memoria que marca este
  parámetro, se lanza la excepción java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. No
  conviene asignar a este parámetro el máximo de la memoria de la
  máquina porque si ya no queda memoria física disponible (por la que
  usa el sistema operativo u otras aplicaciones) puede provocar un
  auténtico dolor de cabeza.
- ***XX:PermSize***=128m: Tamaño de inicio de la memoria de tipo PermGen a
  128Mb. Arrancar la máquina virtual con un valor superior al por
  defecto agiliza la carga de aplicaciones, sobre todo en el caso de
  aplicaciones que hagan uso intensivo de este tipo de memoria (Spring,
  Hibernate…).
- ***XX:MaxPermSize***=128m: Tamaño máximo de la memoria de tipo PermGen a
  128Mb. El valor por defecto son 64Mb. Si la aplicación supera el
  tamaño máximo de memoria para este tipo que marca este
  parámetro, se lanza la excepción java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen
  space. El valor necesario para este parámetro siempre suele ser menor
  que el de la memoria de tipo heap.

Si se quiere especificar un valor distinto de 128Mb, que se utiliza para todos los parámetros como ejemplo para simplificar, bastaría con sustituir el valor 128 del parámetro con el que se desee, siempre que sean múltiplos de 2 (64, 128, 256, 512, 768, 1024, 2048…)
Un ejemplo de configuracion que podrias usar sería:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m"
```